# search in array with specific properties

Tags: algorithm

I have a 2D array in which values are monotonic. How to find all (x,y) where |f(X,Y) – v1| < t in best way.

Comment: If the points in V has the same difference interval in each axis (e.g: 2,4,6 or 1,2,3) you can just do one simple calculation to find its position. If not, you may order your V in both axis (eg. first X and than Y) and find the 4 point that form the smallest Boudingbox to F (2 binary search). And then, just find the closest one. Another idea would be to think each voxel of the grid as an actual voxel. If you do that, you can do something like an hierarchical bounding box to speed up the search.

Comment: I would start with a binary search for `v - t` in the top row and for `v + t` in the bottom row. The resulting interval contains columns which contain entries within the t-surrounding of v. Then, for each column check if the edge values are already in the surrounding (then the entire column is in it). If not, perform a binary search for the remaining interval edge. This way you get all entries, and I doubt that you can do much better. Caching the function might be a good idea if evaluation is expensive.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: value of t is very small since it is just a error correction bound of v. I think searching for v-t in top row and v+t in bottom row wont help since v-t and v+t will be very near and will be on same edge mostly because of monotonicity

Comment: Note that a "binary search in a 2d search space" is a very unusual concept, and the only algorithm I can think of is `O(log(maxx*maxy))` to find _a single_ point on the edge.  Not all edges, and thus not all points.  Once you find a point on the edge you can follow the edge, which can be `O(edge-length)`.  But yeah.  If the points matching your criteria are not a known shape, then there's not going to be a "super fast" method.

Comment: @MooingDuck: F is monotonically non-decreasing in both X and Y. Does that not make things easier than you think?

Comment: @chux: There are no circles involved, I don't think that's relevant

Comment: @chux: I am not getting the idea behind how I could use your link for my stated problem

Comment: @TheGame: Not at all.  Even if T is minescule, the points can form a sinuous line from (0,100) to (100,0), well over 100 points.

Comment: If v+t and v-t are on the same column, you end up with two binary searches in this very column and a total of O(|V| (log width + log height)).

Comment: @MooingDuck: It would be ok for me with any algorithm which could do better than O(|V|nlogn)

Comment: @TheGame: Is this a correct understanding of the problem: http://ideone.com/nImWxb ?  If so, can you put this or another sample in the question?

Comment: @TheGame: Actually, reimagining my algorithm another way, it reduces to `O(maxy*log(maxx))`, so not faster.  (You keep using `V` and `n` in your big-o notation, but give no indication of what `V` and `n` _are_)

Comment: @TheGame: I'm still trying to work out if such a region must be continuous, I don't think it does...

Comment: @TheGame: Points can be discontinuous, though not in the same row/column: http://ideone.com/nImWxb

Comment: @TheGame: Should have been a 41.  Fixed.  Example stands.

Comment: Where does the n in the n lg n come from?

Comment: Agree about lack of applicability of circle routine - mis-read post.  Taking down comments.

Comment: Ah, I see, you care about both of those regions.  (Note that by searching for upper/lower bound (or equal range) you get all the elements that equal, at the same asymptotic cost).  The worst case, where the values you want are exactly on the diagonal, requires O(n) samples to verify (let alone find), so you aren't getting better than that in the worst case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Searching for a value in a matrix with sorted rows and columns is a classic problem. Initialize `row` to its maximum value and `column` to its minimum value. Examine the matrix entry at `row, column`. If it's less than the target value, then increase `column` by one. If it's greater than the target value, then decrease `row` by one. The number of matrix entries inspected is at most `#rows + #columns - 1`.

If this search is continued after the target value is found by decreasing `row` by one (respectively, increasing `column` by one), then we obtain as a byproduct **a determination of which elements are less than** (respectively, less than or equal to) **the target value**. Perform this search algorithm 2|V| times with different target values (less than or equal to `v_i - t`, less than `v_i + t`) to solve the problem with O(|V|n) matrix elements inspected.

Various optimizations are possible. The most obvious is to cache the matrix values. Another is, instead of stepping by just one, use unbounded binary search to determine the most appropriate increment/decrement. It's unclear in prospect whether the higher worst-case constant factor would be overcome by the savings resulting from large changes in neighboring entries.

Example using Mooing Duck's instance:

```
To look for elements in the range (48, 52),
  look for elements less than or equal to 48
    and (separately) elements less than 52.

Looking for elements less or equal to 48:
    Go right (>) if the current element is less than or equal to 48.
    Go down (v) if the current element is greater than 48

50   60   70   80   90  100
 v
40 > 51   60   70   80   90
      v
30   50   52   55   70   80
      v
30   40 > 45 > 46 > 51   52
                     v
30   40   42   45   50   51
                     v
30   40   41   44   49   50
                     v
                  done (access would be out of bounds)

The elements less than or equal to 48 are those in some submatrix containing
  an examined element found to be less than or equal to 48
    and elements to the left and below.
```

Comment: This is much more efficient than I was thinking, assuming that the number of elements in the set is much smaller than the total number of sets.  (Note that you'll almost always hit the max `#rows + #columns - 1` since the set of points for each `v` may be discontinuous, and since there may be multiple points in each row/column, that will ~half the speed.)

Comment: @TheGame Don't search for the middle of the band at all. Search for the edges.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I am sorry that I am still not clear completely. If you dont mind, can you say how it works for the example I gave in the question with F in between 48 and 52 please

Comment: @TheGame Worked the example.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat : say im searching for f = 4 in [4 5 6; 4 4 5]. Here first 4 in first row is found. then go to 5 in first row it is more than f so come down to second 4 in second row. since it is equal to f go to right that is 5. Now we missed the first 4 in row 2 right?

Comment: @TheGame We haven't examined it, but we know that it has to be at most 4, because the row is sorted.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: yeah at most 4 but I wont know whether it is exactly 4 or less than 4 right? I have implemented your algorithm and found that when checking for points with F=v1-t, we are missing some points which have same F value which are in left side but we are taking a right direction since the point we are at is F when coming from top

Comment: @TheGame Right, and it shouldn't matter.

Comment: say my v1-t = 4 in my small example. Since I did not examine first 4 in row 2, I cant take it as f = 4 right?

Comment: @TheGame Yes, you can't assume that there's a 4 there. If the lower end of the excluded range is 4, then it doesn't matter whether it's a 4 or a 3 or something else. If the upper end of the range is 5, then the element, if it's too small, will be ruled out by the search involving the lower end.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat In [4 5 6; 4 4 5] when I want to find values in the range 4 to 5, v1-t = 4 examines 1st, 2nd points in row1 and then second, 3rd points in row2. then when i search for v1+t = 5, it examines 1st, 2nd , 3rd points in row1 and 3rd point in row2. Now first point in row2 also has to be in the result but since it is not examined it is missing in my result. How do I include points like that in the results is my question.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat For 2D, this is best algorithm. But if I have three dimensions i.e. each point in the space is f(x,y,z) with same characteristics as 2D, would the same algorithm work and how should I modify it to find same all (x,y,z) such that |f(x,y,z) - v1| < t ?

Comment: @TheGame That's another question entirely.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat : Yeah I will probably post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Let me turn my comment into an answer:

It's possible to solve the *n* × *n* problem in at most 4*n* − 3 evaluations, and I conjecture that this bound is optimal, or at least close to optimal.

The algorithm is as follows:

1. Start at top left, i.e. at *x* = 1, *y* = *n*.
2. Evaluate the function *f*(*x*,*y*).  If *f*(*x*,*y*) < *v*<sub>1</sub> + *t*, increment *x*, else decrement *y*.
3. Repeat from step 2, until *y* < 1 or *x* > *n*, i.e. until you hit the bottom or right edge of the grid.

You've now found the upper edge of the region where −*t* < *f*(*x*,*y*) − *v*<sub>1</sub> < *t*.  Now do the same for the lower edge; that is, apply the algorithm above, but replace the condition in step 2 with *f*(*x*,*y*) < *v*<sub>1</sub> − *t*.

Each edge takes at most 2*n* − 1 function evaluations, and they overlap on at least one point (*x* = 1, *y* = *n*), so 4*n* − 3 evaluations should be enough in the worst case.

---

While I haven't managed to prove the optimality of the algorithm given above, I *can* prove that any solution must require at least 2*n* − 2 function evaluations in the worst case.  Specifically, I can exhibit a family of bimonotone functions *f* on an *n* × *n* grid, such that, even if the value of *f* at all but 2*n* − 2 of the grid points is known in advance, the function must still be evaluated separately at each of the remaining points in order to determine which side of the boundary those points fall on.

An example of such a family of functions is given by *f*(*x*,*y*) = *x* + *y* + *ε*(*x*,*y*), with *v*<sub>1</sub> = *n* + 1, *t* = 1, and |*ε*(*x*,*y*)| < 1 for all *x*, *y*.  It's easy to see that such functions are monotone increasing in both *x* and *y* (at least when restricted to the grid points), and that:

- points on the diagonal line from (*x* = 1, *y* = *n*) to (*x* = *n*, *y* = 1) always fall within the tolerance region,
- points one square away from the diagonal may or may not fall within tolerance, depending on *ε*(*x*,*y*), and
- points more than one square away from the diagonal never fall within tolerance.

The uncertain super- and subdiagonals each contain *n* − 1 points, each of which needs to be tested separately — we can freely choose the function *ε*(*x*,*y*) so as to make any subset of those points fall within the tolerance region.  Thus, even with this extra advance knowledge, at least 2*n* − 2 tests are needed to exactly determine the boundaries of the tolerance region.

In fact, this argument can be trivially tweaked to raise the lower bound to 2*n* − 1.  Going beyond that, however, seems to require more complicated arguments, even if it seems intuitively obvious that, without such extra knowledge, we should need at least close to 4*n* evaluations in the worst case.  Still, this proof, combined with the algorithm above, at least shows that the worst-case asymptotic complexity of this problem is Θ(*n*).

---

Also, in *d* ≥ 3 dimensions, this problem can be trivially solved in O(*n*<sup>d−1</sup>) function evaluations by dividing the grid into two-dimensional slices and applying the algorithm given above separately to each slice.  Further, I believe that a fairly straightforwards generalization of the lower bound proof above can be used to show that the worst-case complexity of the *d*-dimensional version of this problem is, indeed, Θ(*n*<sup>d−1</sup>).

Comment: I believe the argument given above could be generalized to prove a lower bound of 2 n^(d-1) - 2 evaluations for the d-dimensional case. The naive slicing method requires less twice that, so it's at least within a constant factor of optimal. (And, in fact, it's intuitively obvious that the lower bound cannot be tight.)

Comment: Essentially, the problem is that, if you want to find the *exact* boundary of the tolerance region, you're going to have to walk it point by point anyway, and that takes O(n^(d-1)) evaluations in the worst case. Of course, some fancy binary search algorithm might be able to find an *approximate* solution quicker, or maybe even do better for the exact solution *on average*, but if what you care about is worst-case complexity for an exact solution, the "naive" but reliable edge-walking method seems optimal, or close to it.

Comment: OK, that's a different problem. If the surface *must* lie inside the tolerance region everywhere, I suspect the problem is still O(n^(d-1)) in the worst case (that being, specifically, the case where the tolerance region is very narrow and almost but not quite flat), but there might be ways to do it more efficiently on average, if the tolerance region is usually fairly wide, or if you can accept a small chance of the surface going outside the tolerance region.

Comment: Anyway, you might want to spend a few moments thinking about what your *actual* constraints and requirements for this surface really are, and then ask a new question about finding such a surface (either here, or perhaps on our sister sites for [math.se], [cs.se] or [scicomp.se]).

Answer (score 1):

You find all points for a single value in `O(2*log n + 4 * n)`.

First, you should find the interval of points, which have acceptable values for the first row. You can do this with two binary searches. Thus, you will obtain `c1` and `c2`, such that `|f(0, c) - v1| < t` for all `c` in `[c1, c2]`. This initial step takes about `O(log n)`.

Then, since the function is monotonically non-decreasing in both X and Y dimensions, you would know that when you increment the row, those two values `c1` and `c2` would only decrease. Since you can decrement them a total of `c1 + c2 <= 2*n` times, and since you can increment the row `n` times for both values, we get an upper bound of `4*n` function calls.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need the initial binary search; even without it, you can solve the problem in at most 2 * (m + n) - 3 function evaluations for an m*n grid (i.e. at most 397 for 100*100) just by walking each threshold starting from the top left corner.

Comment: @TheGame: Start at top left, x = 1, y = 100. Evaluate function there. If f(x,y) < v1 + t, increment x, else decrement y. Repeat until hit bottom or right edge. You've now found the upper edge of the region; now do the same for the lower edge. Each edge takes at most 199 evaluations, and they overlap on at least one point (1, 100), so 397 evaluations should be enough even in worst case.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen It seems your idea is quite similar to David Eisenstat's. When I posted this, he already shared his answer, which has better upper bounds (no binary search). Nevertheless, I decided to leave my answer, because in some cases it should converge faster (i.e. less function calls) than his approach.

Comment: @TheGame You can use lower bound algorithm to find c1, and equivalently, upper bound to find c2.

Comment: @TheGame: You can handle the 3D case trivially in O(n²) time by running the 2D algorithm once for each value of the third coordinate. I don't think it's possible to do significantly better in general, at least not in the worst case, because an approximately linear boundary in 3D can have O(n²) independent elements that each need to be individually tested to see which side of the boundary they lie on.